# Autostart Apps in order - Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, boot, automation

Is there some way to autostart apps in Vista so you can control which one is started first, second, third etc. For example if I want to start Outlook, Visual Studio, Dreamweaver, IE, Firefox in that order, and to have them appear in the taskbar like that.

I added them into the autostart-folder but Vista didn't start the apps in the order I wanted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there is not really an easy way to launch in order other than creating a batch file that launches them in sequence with a wait in between. If you just launch, you would have a problem as it does not go to the next without the first one closing.

Your best bet is probably to download [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), and place your applications in different sections of start, as naturally a few sections here get processed before others.

Comment: It's not going to be pretty, though. It means apps have to wait one for the other to fully start, right?

Comment: Yes :(

Comment: I wonder how this can be the accepted answer, while Startup Delayer proposed below is a much better solution? :-/

Comment: Maybe he just tried mine and it accomplished what he wanted

Comment: I did a script that handled it, I wanted several instances of some apps to start and this worked very well.

Answer (score 5):

[Startup Delaye](http://www.r2.com.au/software.php?page=2&show=startdelay)r does this very well. Set the order and even push back some apps to start several minutes after boot to help performance.

Comment: does what it says on the tin :) +1

Answer (score 0):

If your point is to have the taskbar buttons in a specific order, you can use [**Taskbar Shuffle**](http://nerdcave.webs.com/) to move them to the desired position on the taskbar.

It also allows changing the position of icons in the notification area (also [wrongly known](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx) as the System Tray).

**Features**:

- Full 32-bit and 64-bit support
- Reorder your taskbar buttons by
  dragging and dropping them
- Reorder
  your tray icons in the same way
- Reorder tasks in a grouped button's
  popup menu in the same way
- Middle-click to close programs on
  your taskbar
- Works with UltraMon
  (version 3+ only) taskbars
- Tweak
  taskbar button grouping